# Php login panel

Tags: php

I have developed a small application. I created a login panel for it. I have only one user so, I hard coded both user name and password. Below is the code but it is not working.I don’t have any db for this bcoz, it will have only 1 user.
Any help ii be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

```
<?php    
if(($_POST['na'] = 'admin') == ($_POST['pwd'] = 'zucker'))
{
    header("location:first.php");
}
else
{
    header("location:index.php?msg=enter correct user name and password");
}    
?>
```

Comment: Formatted the code so we could actually read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, from what I can decipher from your code - you have = and == applied incorrectly. Where you have = you want == and where you have == you want &&

```
if (($_POST['na']=='admin') && ($_POST['pwd']=='zucker')) {
  header('location:first.php')
};
```

I hope this isn't how your login model is going to work - whats to stop just anyone going directly to first.php?

Comment: To clarify Mailslut's words: = will assign the value 'admin' to the 'na' entry in the _POST dictionary. == will compare the values. And you wanted both to count, so you need && ('and') to make sure both comparisons are valid. You (daffodil) may want to pick up a beginner's guide to php first, before taking on things like security (no offence).

Comment: Remember to always exit() or die() after the header calls

Answer (score 0):

To avoid some Notice errors and other bugs:

```
<?php 

$na     = isset($_POST['na']) ? $_POST['na'] : false;
$pwd    = isset($_POST['pwd']) ? $_POST['pwd'] : false;
$submit = isset($_POST['submit']) ? true : false;

if ($submit) {

  if ($na == 'admin' && $pwd == 'zucker') {

    header("location:first.php");
    exit(); // Make sure nothing else gets sent

  } else {

    header("location:index.php?msg=enter correct user name and password");
    exit(); // Make sure nothing else gets sent

  }

}
?>
```

Here's a slightly more advanced example:

```
<?php 
$na     = isset($_POST['na']) ? $_POST['na'] : false;
$pwd    = isset($_POST['pwd']) ? $_POST['pwd'] : false;
$submit = isset($_POST['submit']) ? true : false;

// Accounts array (append as you wish)
$accounts  =  array(
                'admin'  =>  '4635c0015b2084afcc7cb39593545e06',
                'foo'    =>  '37b51d194a7513e45b56f6524f2d51f2'
              );

// form complete?
if ($submit && $na && pwd) {

  if (isset($accounts[$na]) && md5($accounts[$na]) == $pwd) {

    header("location:first.php");
    exit(); // Make sure nothing else gets sent

  } else {

    header("location:index.php?msg=enter correct user name and password");
    exit(); // Make sure nothing else gets sent

  }

}
?>
```

Comment: its pretty pointless adding md5 to a hard coded login, if the hacker was reading his password then he would already have server access :/

Comment: Not necessarily; This can cover a few bases i.e. If the PHP binary crashes, or if the server is incorrectly configured. It's happened to many large sites before, even Facebook - http://techcrunch.com/2007/08/11/facebook-source-code-leaked/

It'll also keep out prying eyes on shared hosting where some people may have shell access. 

I totally agree though, if you're going to implement something like my second snippet then it's probabaly worth using a database of some sort.

Comment: Both of u hv helped me.Thnx a lot

Comment: the xample works but is so written over that the guy who asked the question probably wont understand what he did wrong.
database is absolutely not necessary. i'd suggest dynamically salting the md5 hash with a token and the username and not even include the username in the script.